# issue on link with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have tab bar with links inside which give a strange behavior on Firefox.

When I click on a link on chrome the URL is "http://localhost:8080/netmg/view/home#agregateShowMode=site&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=1" and the tab is found correctly.
But when I use Firefox with the same code the URL become
"http://localhost:8080/netmg/view/home"

HTML code :

```
<div class="tabs" id="tab-home-view">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li id="General" class="active"><a href="" onclick="javascript:App.workOnHomeTabs(this, '0');">General</a></li>
    <li id="device"><a href="" onclick="javascript:App.workOnHomeTabs(this, '1');" >Device</a></li>
    <li id="link"><a href="" onclick="javascript:App.workOnHomeTabs(this, '2');">Link</a></li>
    <li id="Service"><a href="" onclick="javascript:App.workOnHomeTabs(this, '3');">Service</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS CODE :

```
App.workOnHomeTabs = function (obj, toAppend) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.includes("&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=")) {
    obj.href = url.replace(/(&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=)\d+/, '$1' + toAppend);
    }
    else {
      obj.href = url + "&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=" + toAppend;
    }
    Ext.select('#tab-home-view ul li').removeCls('active');
    Ext.get(obj).up('li').addCls('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.includes("&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=")) {
  ...
}
```

In the if statement above, you invoke the **"includes"** method of a String. This method is an **experimental technology** (as specified in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and it shouldn't be used, because it is pretty new.

**Google Chrome** has already implemented this new feature, so when you click in the "a" element it works as expected and redirects you to the correct page.

However, **Firefox** hasn't implemented it yet, so when you execute that function it throws an error and the "a" element where you clicked behaves like a normal link and reloads the current page because you left the "href" attribute empty.

```
<a href=""></a>
```

---

If I were you I would change the if statement to this one, that works on every browser:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf("&activeTabHomeAgregateSite=") != -1) {
  ...
}
```

and I would fill the "href" attribute of the "a" elements with a hash symbol, like this:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

This will prevent your page to be reloaded when there's an error on the execution of the event.